# How to find the difference between bash completion rules on different hosts?

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete

In my desktop computer with opensuse 13.1 I can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> in something like

```
ls *.dat[Tab]
```

and I get the autocompletion or with [TAB TAB] a list of possible matches. However, in my laptop with opensuse 13.2 this doesn't work. Only common completions, like

```
ls file[Tab]
```

is working. How can I get the first case also working?

Answer (score 4):

You should check the version of your `bash-completion` package, e.g.

```
dpkg -l bash-completion
```

and upgrade it, maybe you've the old version.

You can check list all the current completion routines bound via:

```
complete -p
```

To compare the rules manually, save them into files and check the differences, e.g.

```
linux1$ complete -p > rules1.lst
linux2$ complete -p > rules2.lst
# Place two files in one folder. 
linux1$ diff -u rules1.lst rules2.lst
```

To check manually for the differences, look in:

- `/etc/bash_completion`, `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` files,
- files in `/etc/bash_completion.d` folder,
- in user folder: `~/.bash_completion`.

See also:

- [Standard place for user defined bash_completion.d scripts?](https://serverfault.com/q/506612/130437)
- [An introduction to bash completion](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/316/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1)
- [Bash Completion Official Homepage](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/)

Comment: For the manual approach, I don't have any /etc/bash_completion, /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion or ~/.bash_completion. And for /etc/bash_completion.d it seem a collection of rules for particular programs.

Comment: In the diff case, after get the differences, should I execute the missing lines? Why not just execute the rule1.lst (the good gone) directly in linux2?

Comment: I think you should find the source of these missing lines (e.g. `/etc/bash_completion.d`) and start from there. If these rules are provided by some scripts, find them and check where they belong (to which packages, e.g. `dpkg -S`).